# Log out after X minutes turning itself back on

Tags: macos, system-settings, preferences

This is driving me insane. The checkbox in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General Tab > Advanced > Logout after X minutes of inactivity` turns itself back on whenever I move away from the settings screen. I recorded a gif to illustrate this:

[image: Sorry for the low quality]

Anyone knows why this is happening? Is it some new antivirus setting? Some remote setting? Some MacOS setting? Btw I'm running latest El Capitan

#### EDIT

I tried using Automator to disable this again every 5 minutes. Didn't work haha.
I was also able to figure out the file where this particular pref is saved, running `sudo fs_usage -w`. It's here:

`/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

running `defaults read` shows me the preference is `AutoLogOutDelay`

If I run:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay 0
```

The computer freezes for 5 minutes. I have no idea what's going on

#### Edit 2

Found a [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6501019?start=0&tstart=0) from Apple discussions. The last message in the thread points to `Profile Manager, General > Login Window > Options` I will try to check with the network manager.

No, it's off there too. Looking further into `fs_usage` I noticed something strange. A process `VShieldScanner.3263` is editing the preferences, namely McAffee ...

Comment: Have you tried "locking" the changes? (click the padlock to the right of "Advanced" when you make the change)

Comment: Yes, this has no effect :(

Comment: Is there anyone else who has administrator access to your computer, and/or anyone who might have some management over it (such as it being on a corporate network)?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I am the only one facing this issue. I will ask the administrator. In the mean time, I found a temporary solution. Xcode prevents logout, so keeping it open partially solves the problem. Still very frustrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug in McAffee

Updating to version `10.2` [fixes the problem](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/26000/PD26588/en_US/ens_1020_rn_0_00_en-us.pdf)